# Arguing that the distribution is not normal

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

Assume someone claims that they sampled i.i.d. $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ (let's say $k=10$) from standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.
They claim that the sampled values are **exactly** $x_1=x_2= \dots = x_k = 0$.
My reaction would be "you are lying", i.e. there is no way in hell $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ would be exactly the same infinite-precision numbers.
Am I correct and how do I show that formally?

Intuitively, I want to say that the probability that we sample the same number $10$ times has probability $0$. The problem is that I can make this argument for any sequence, since probability of getting any fixed sequence is $0$. In fact, sequence $x_1=\cdots=x_k=0$ maximizes $p(x_1) \cdot p(x_2) \cdots p(x_k)$, where $p$ is the PDF (which also doesn't seem to imply anything).

What is the formal argument? I'm stuck on even formulating the exact mathematical statement I want to say (as I explained above, "the probability of getting this sequence is $0$" doesn't imply anything). While using normality tests I can upper-bound the probability of this happening with some small positive number, I want to show that the probability of this happening is $0$.

I think this should be a standard question. In this case, the reference is appreciated.

**EDIT after the answer was posted**: To clarify, I would like an argument that captures the following case: assume that we sampled $k=2$ points and that $x_2 - x_1$ is rational. Then I want to say that this event still has probability $0$. I do can say that "the probability of having a rational distance is $0$". The problem is the same as before: for any fixed difference I can similarly say that the probability of having exactly this difference is $0$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150057/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry-arguing-that-the-distribution-is-not-normal); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You yourself just explained why no formal argument is available to prove what you want to prove:

> Assume someone claims that they sampled i.i.d. $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ (let's say $k=10$) from standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.
> They claim that the sampled values are **exactly** $x_1=x_2= \dots = x_k = 0$.
> My reaction would be "you are lying", i.e. there is no way in hell $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ would be exactly the same infinite-precision numbers.
> Am I correct and how do I show that formally?
>
> Intuitively, I want to say that the probability that we sample the same number $10$ times has probability $0$. The problem is that I can make this argument for any sequence, since probability of getting any fixed sequence is $0$. In fact, sequence $x_1=\cdots=x_k=0$ maximizes $p(x_1) \cdot p(x_2) \cdots p(x_k)$, where $p$ is the PDF (which also doesn't seem to imply anything).

Because ( as specified in your comments to @lulu ) you are working with a continuous distribution and an idealized, infinite-precision sampling process, every particular outcome $\Bbb{R}^k \ni \vec{x} := (x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)$ has probability zero.
(*In fact, $\vec{0} := (0, 0, ..., 0)$ is the modal outcome of the probability density function of a normally distributed $k$-dimensional random variable $\vec{X_k} \sim \mathcal{N}(\vec{0}, 1)$, so in some sense this is the outcome we should **least** doubt!*)
Even if you want to say that the probability of $\vec{X_k}$ lying in some hyperplane $x_n = x_m$ is $0$, which is certainly true, (a) that doesn't establish impossibility and (b) every potential outcome lies in infinitely many hyperplanes, all of which individually have probability zero.
This is why @lulu was trying to help you out and point you in the direction of finite precision, hypothesis testing, and significance levels, because only an **actually impossible** result (and not just a probability zero one) could totally rule out the observed data having some particular continuous distribution.

Comment: Thank you. To summarize, in the infinite-precision arithmetic this kind of testing is impossible? (I don't think lulu tried to do what you claim they tried to do).

Comment: Well, you *can* still do a hypothesis test, based on Glivenko-Cantelli and the DKW inequality. I'll write up what that looks like when I have some free time. I think once $k$ is in the double digits, an observation of $\vec{0}$ would probably trigger you to reject a null hypothesis that the sampling distribution is $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, at the 5% or 1% significance level. *But under no circumstance could you say, **with 100% confidence,** that the other person is lying about the sampling distribution being $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.*

Comment: Thank you. My questions was about 100% confidence, so no need to write about these tests.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_k$ be a set of jointly independent and identically distributed random variables. Now, after performing some experiment suppose we obtain a sample $\{ x_1,x_2,...,x_k \}$ of $k$ results such that $X_i = x_i$ for $i=1,2,...,k$.

Even if some or all results in the sample are the same exact value, we can perform one of several statistical tests to determine whether the underlying distribution of $X_i$ is indeed normal:

- The [Shapiro-Wilk Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) tests the null hypothesis that the results $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ were sampled from a normally distributed population. Hence, if the p-value of the corresponding test statistic is sufficiently low (that is, less than your chosen Type I error $\alpha$), then you may reject the null hypothesis and conclude the data *did not* originate from a normal distribution (with probability $\alpha$ of being mistaken). This test actually performs quite well relative to the others below, especially for small to moderate sample sizes.
- The (One-Sample) [Kolmogorov-Smirnov (K-S) Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) tests the null hypothesis that the results $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ were sampled from a given reference distribution (normal or otherwise). It does this by quantifying the difference between the empirical cumulative distribution function of the observed data and the cumulative distribution function of the given reference distribution. This test typically requires larger sample sizes to perform as good as others on this list.
- The [Anderson-Darling Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test) tests the null hypothesis that the results $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ were sampled from a given reference distribution (normal or otherwise). It works similarly to the One-Sample K-S Test, but it places more weight on the tails of the given distribution. It is particularly sensitive to detecting departures from normality.
- The [D'Agostino's $K^2$ Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Agostino%27s_K-squared_test) tests the null hypothesis that the results $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ were sampled from a normally distrubited population. It combines information regarding sample skewness and kurtosis to assess a departure from normality that would otherwise be expected had the sample come from a normal distribution.
- The [Lilliefors Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test) tests the null hypothesis that the results $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ were sampled from a normally distrubited population. It is particularly useful in situations where the mean and variance of the parent distribution is unknown. Somewhat similar to the One-Sample K-S Test, its test statistic quantifies the maximum difference between the empirical distribution function of the observed data and the normal cumulative distribution function; however, unlike the One-Sample K-S Test, the Lilliefors test is better suited for smaller sample sizes.

Again, any of the above statistical tests will convey the probability that the samples $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ come from a normal distribution, **even if some or all of the samples happen to be the same value.**

You are perfectly correct in presuming the results $x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_k = 0$ are suspicious given the claim they were independently sampled under a standard normal distribution, and any one of the above tests would back you up on that, especially for large $k$. The reason is as $k$ increases the likelihood of observing a sample variance $s^2 > 0$ increases as well. Hence, we expect there to be *variation* in the observed results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me clarify my point of concern. Assume a different scenario: only two values are exactly the same (e.g. assume that $x_1=x_2=0$, exactly, and $x_3, \ldots, x_{10}$ are truly sampled from the normal distribution). I want to say that this already has probability 0 (in some sense that I don't know how to define). Do these tests capture this situation?

Comment: @Dmitry All tests above would assess whether such a sample originated from a standard normal distribution. This is true whether some or all observations in the sample are exactly the same, $0$ or otherwise. However, note that *in practice* the probability of obtaining mulitple values that are exactly the same is not $0$. Any device used to measure a variable has finite resolution, so it may assign all true measurements in the interval $(x-0.5, x+0.5)$ to the real number $x$. Hence, you could have multiple measurements that *appear* the same even though each was actually different.

Comment: 1) I'm talking about the theoretical infinite-precision scenario (as in the question), not the practical scenario (in practical scenario, it's obvious that the probability is not 0 due to rounding). 2) I don't see how e.g. the first test captures the scenario I outlined in the comment. I want to argue that it can't happen with non-zero probability. The test will detect nothing of the sort, I believe.

Comment: Think about it this way: assume that someone gave you infinite-precision samples  $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ for some large $k$ such that $x_1=x_2$ and $x_3, \ldots, x_k$ are indeed sampled from the normal distribution. Will you be "Looks OK" or will you argue that these are definitely not samples from normal distribution? In the latter case, what will be your argument? Note that since most elements are indeed from normal distribution, statistical tests won't work (AFAICT).

Comment: ANY sequence of real numbers randomly sampled from a distribution has probability $0$. This is true whether some or all of the sampled values are the same. This is because is the probability of sampling any single real number is $\frac{1}{|\mathbb{R}|}$ which approaches $0$.

Comment: So your answer to that question is "Looks OK"?

Comment: If someone gave me infinite-precision samples $x_1,x_2,…,x_k$ for some large $k$ such that $x_1=x_2$ and they claimed all samples were sampled from the normal distribution, **then I would use one of the tests above**, such as the Shapiro-Wilk Test, to determine the probability that the samples $x_1,x_2,…,x_k$ were sampled from a normal distribution. If the probability was small, then I would say "unlikely." If the probability was not small, then I would say "Looks OK." *ALL of the statistical tests I presented in my answer will work in the scenario you presented*

Comment: the tests evaluate the probability of the observed data coming from the normal distribution, even if some or all of the samples are the same values.

Comment: "there is a non-zero probability associated with obtaining such a sample from a normal distribution" - these are big news for me, please elaborate (again, we are talking about infinite precision).

Comment: even if some or all of your sampled values are the same, your sample of values $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ will have a particular mean, variance, skew, kurtosis, set of percentiles, etc. Generally speaking, the statistical tests above compute the probability of obtaining a sample having those exact characteristics (or characteristics that are even more "unusual" or extreme) under the assumption that the values are all sampled from a normal distribution. If the probability is low, then you conclude the values were *unlikely* to have been sampled from a normal distribution.

Comment: I know how statistical tests work. By "statistical tests won't work" I meant that they won't detect that $x_1=x_2$ (if $k$ is large, it won't affect the result of the tests). Anyway, I got the answer from Rivers.

Comment: the fact that $x_1=x_2$ is irrelevant

Comment: Yeah, I got your point already.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(0, \dotsc, 0)$ has the greatest product of probability densities of any sequence, but its probability is still $0$, just like every other sequence. That being said, if we did sample $k$ exact values from a normal distribution, and all of them were exactly $0$, you would be right to assume that there's something wrong with the sampling mechanism.

A sequence of $k$ zeros would be far more surprising than, say, a sequence of $k$ irrational numbers with no discernible pattern. However, the reason for this has nothing to do with probability. It's just that, as humans, we see $0$ as a very special, commonly encountered number. $0$ means nothing special to a random variable sampled from a normal distribution, so to see it appear in such a random variable is particularly surprising.

Comment: I don't understand - what's the mathematical argument?

Comment: @Dmitry There is no mathematical argument because what you're trying to argue is inherently nonmathematical.